# How to create iso in customized ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian

I have customized my ubuntu 16.04 fully.
Now i want to make it's iso image how can i do that??
I tried with pinguy,systemback,respin but it didn't worked out.
Please help.

Comment: I recommend you to not do that, it's not a clean way, (By the way, if you `really` want to do that, check this link: https://linuxhint.com/customize_ubuntu_iso_create_spin)

Comment: Hey, thank you for your support i believe this will work for me.

Comment: Hi, Cubic is saying to install tools via chroot terminal, i have pre installed all the tools and custom make it. will it delete my all data?